# Want to run a program on some unknown system

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2005

I have been working on a VS 2005 project and have successfully generated an exe file which works fine on my system. However when I tried to run it on some other pc it didnt run. It throws up the error message "the system cannot run the specified program". Can someone tell me how to make my code immune to such message i.e. system independent?

platform used: Windows XP, VS 2005

the extension of all my code files is cpp but I know only c and thats what I wrote inside them.

Comment: @bubble: What is the other OS on which you are trying to run it?

Comment: without the exact error message, this is going to be a bit hard to answer.

Comment: Knowing that you are compiling with VS2005, I suppose it's safe to assume you are trying to run this on another Windows-running computer.  But if your are _compiling_ the code on the other computer, then most of the time, it should work no problems as long as you stick to using the standard libraries.  Though we won't be able to judge anything unless we see what your code looks like.

Comment: @Als its XP. But can I make it os independent i.e. atleast for windows?

Comment: @Mat that the exact error message. nothing more nothing less.

Comment: @Jeff I am using some non standard libraries like opencv. What should I do then?

Comment: Can you compile a hello world program and get it to run on the problematic computer?

Comment: @icktoofay that will take a long time to answer. But let me tell you I got this error message from two PCs, one with windows7 other with XP

Comment: @bubble - It will always work on **some** machines, if they have already installed another program using the same runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen before exe created on Windows Sp1 not working on SP2 and problems such as that.
[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikolad/archive/2005/06/09/427101.aspx) should help you perhaps.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this when you run on a different version of Windows that doesn't have some DLL you depend on.  The easiest thing to do is statically link the C runtime (that's the usual culprit) and use depends.exe to see if there are any others.

Comment: can you tell me how to "statically link the c runtime". I have no clue.

Answer (score 2):

You will almost certainly need to create an installer that installs your executable and any non-OS-included DLL's it relies upon.  It is not always possible or desirable to statically link all dependencies.  You can in many cases simply copy the DLL's to the same folder as the executable.

By default, even the C/C++ standard library is provided by a DLL.  While the MSVCRT.DLL used by VC++ 6 is included with the OS since later editions Win95, the MSVCRT required by VS2005 is not included with XP installations (other versions I do not know).  The run-time support is included VC redistributes package.  You may need to arrange for your installer to include that installation, or you could be more selective is you know your dependencies.

Some Win32 API calls if you are using them are dependent on the OS version (check the documentation), but if you built and rin it on XP, it should normally work of any subsequent version of Windows. You need to define various API version macros if you want to extend support to earlier versions of Windows (which seems unlikley).

Answer (score 0):

You might need to install the [VS 2005 redistributables](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=200B2FD9-AE1A-4A14-984D-389C36F85647) on the other machines, depending on how you have compiled your program.

Comment: I dont have control over other machines. What is need should come from my program.

Comment: @bubble - It is just that if your program is **the first** program compiled with VS2005 on a particular machine, the DLLs will be missing.